# The Android Activity Stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have been studying the Android Activity Stack. The book mentions the following:

> Android uses a last-in-first-out collection of all the currently running
>   activities.

However, when I look at the diagram:

[image]

It appears that the first activity to be put on the stack is the first activity to be removed off the Activity stack (hence a FIFO queue rather than a LIFO queue). Any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are we talking about how activities are killed when the system needs to free resources, or are we talking about how old activities re-appear when the current activity is killed by the user? I think that the word "collection" in the book simply refers to the stack of activities, not garbage collection, and that the "removed to free resources" in the diagram is about freeing resources by killing activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A notion of `LIFO` (activity stack) refers only to vertical arrows on the diagram you posted, i.e.

- *last in* - last activity X displayed on top of others
- *first out* - the same last activity X to be removed/destroyed when user presses back button

Don't be confused with bottom arrow *Removed to free resources* - there is a completely separate mechanism for handling that by OS which involves [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) calls.

Answer (score 0):

It mean that Suppose you start the Activity A then Activity B then press back from Activity B then again press back from Activity A.

It simply mean that Last activity pop first that is called LIFO.